# MVC3 Html Hidden Size limit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, size, hiddenfield

Is there a size limit that the HTML.Hidden can take ?I have the following code, which works when i only put ViewData["key"]="12345" but when the "12345 is too much data the htmlfield is empty.

```
 @Html.Hidden("hid" + param.Parameter.Name, ViewData["hid"+param.Parameter.Name])
```

And when I add the ViewData["hid"+param.Parameter.Name] in javascript function to alert the values, the entire string is there.

kind regards

Comment: How much data are you trying to put into it when it fails?

Comment: About 1900 GUID ids, i know this is not best practice, but they are insisting. And I do not have time to work out another plan.

Comment: Are you setting value on ajax call ?

Comment: nope, i am adding the values to the Viewdata in my controller action, when doing this with ajax call in javascript all is working.

Comment: Looks like the values is not rendered on the hidden controls if the values is more than 4000 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTTP POST verb to submit the form the limit is controlled by the `maxRequestLength` attribute of the [`<httpRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) element in your web.config. The default value is 4096 KB:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
```

Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("hid", string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, 40000).Select(x => "a")))
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

successfully uploads all the 40K `a` to the server.

On the other hand if you are using an HTTP GET verb to submit the form then, since the values are sent in the query string, there will be a limit. This limit will vary across different browsers. IIRC it was around 4K in IE.